# True Caller Search API for Android

Tags: android

Is there is True Caller API for Android App exist, where can I search Name against Mobile number?

Comment: Down voter please mention the reason.

Comment: I want to know whether that profile is verified on truecaller or not..any idea how to fetch that? I'm unable to see any variable in TrueProfile for that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can use the `Truecaller SDK`.

Here is small snippet which you can use to get the profile Details and Verify it by using the `SDK`.

> You can trigger the Truecaller profile verification dialog anywhere in
> your app flow by calling the following method

```
TrueSDK.getInstance().getUserProfile()
```

Add the following condition in the onActivityResult method:

```
TrueSDK.getInstance().onActivityResultObtained( this,resultCode, data);
```

In your selected `Activity`

Either make the `Activity` implement **`ITrueCallback`** or create an instance. This interface has 2 methods: `onSuccesProfileShared(TrueProfile)` and `onFailureProfileShared(TrueError)`

```
private final ITrueCallback sdkCallback = new ITrueCallback() {
    
     @Override
     public void onSuccessProfileShared(@NonNull final TrueProfile trueProfile) {
 
    // This method is invoked when the truecaller app is installed on the device and the user gives his
    // consent to share his truecaller profile 
    
      Log.d( TAG, "Verified Successfully : " + trueProfile.firstName );
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailureProfileShared(@NonNull final TrueError trueError) {
    // This method is invoked when some error occurs or if an invalid request for verification is made 
 
      Log.d( TAG, "onFailureProfileShared: " + trueError.getErrorType() );
     }

};
```

you can find here the full implementation of the `SDK`

[https://github.com/truecaller/android-sdk](https://github.com/truecaller/android-sdk-sample)

https://developer.truecaller.com/for-mobile-apps

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I want to know whether that truecaller profile is verified on truecaller or not..any idea how to fetch that? I'm unable to see any variable in TrueProfile for that..

Comment: how will i get information on other user phone number?

Comment: There is a Boolean Variable `isVerified` you can get this boolean to check about verified users or not.

Rest they have emptied their Android SDK Repo. I will try to make a small implementation on all of this basic information.

happy coding.

Comment: I am looking for api which they implemented on their website where u just enter a phone number and get details. How to add a new number in twilio with name, company without verification

Comment: Just got email from truecaller : We do not provide any API access as the same would amount to violation of user privacy.


Truecaller SDK is a user-consent based product, wherein users explicitly have to allow sharing their profile with your service.


Learn more here: https://docs.truecaller.com/truecaller-sdk/